# Cassandra writetime primary key

Tags: cassandra

As we know we can use writetime to get the write time of the non-primary key data. but is there any method or function to get the primary key writetime??*emphasized text*

Answer (score 1):

The [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9312) that wishes to enable the possibility of reading the writetime of a row is 5 years old now and does not look like it's anywhere near implementation.

That being said, since there is no default support what I would probably be doing if I were in your situation is analyze the data model and see if I can use another column (probably one that is inserted the first time but never updated) or adding a new column. If all operations change all the fields and there is no way to know application side what operation is the first then lightweight transactions could help but at the cost of increased overhead and not being a nice design pattern. If you are interested in the partition key, you could use writetime on a static column but that again depends more on your data model.

Hope this helped,
Mike.